# Query string changes the parallel processing behavior of RestController in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm new to Spring Boot and currently checking how my sample API using @RestController works. The behavior of this method when receiving two simultaneous requests seems to change depending on whether I attach a query string or not.

Here is my sample code:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
           
        String str = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
            log.info(str);
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

When I call this method without query string from two clients at the same time (http://localhost:8080/test), it works sequentially. The log will be like this:

```
2021-09-16 18:20:14.914  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.TestController          : e909a1ba-835c-4ecf-adfc-460cb03665eb
2021-09-16 18:20:14.914  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.TestController          : e909a1ba-835c-4ecf-adfc-460cb03665eb
2021-09-16 18:20:14.908  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.TestController          : cdd31851-a2d7-4c24-9369-c90b9926b65f
2021-09-16 18:20:14.908  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.TestController          : cdd31851-a2d7-4c24-9369-c90b9926b65f
```

The UUIDs in the log are completely separated, so it seems that the second request is being processed after the first one is completed.

On the other hand, when I call it with two different query strings (/test?a=1 and /test?a=2), it works in parallel. The UUIDs are mixed.

```
2021-09-16 18:20:14.928  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.TestController          : e909a1ba-835c-4ecf-adfc-460cb03665eb
2021-09-16 18:20:14.928  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.TestController          : cdd31851-a2d7-4c24-9369-c90b9926b65f
2021-09-16 18:20:14.928  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.TestController          : e909a1ba-835c-4ecf-adfc-460cb03665eb
2021-09-16 18:20:14.928  INFO 19480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.TestController          : cdd31851-a2d7-4c24-9369-c90b9926b65f
```

This method doesn't use query strings so I think the only difference of two cases are the URLs that the Spring Boot receives.

What are the internal processing differences between the two cases?

Comment: i think you could have a false assumption here: just because the UUIDs show up sequentially does not necessarily mean they are being processed sequentially. It could just mean they are passed to the threads in a manner that appears sequential, and by some chance thread 1 finishes before thread 2 starts. also, in the second log, all of those messages are written at once, meaning they don't necessarily are in the correct order.

Comment: How many times did you run both tests? Did you get consistent results to support your assumption of sequential Vs. parallel execution? Also, logging plays a factor here. Instead of logging would you please put the `UUID` in a map with a timestamp and log it once outside the `for` loop? Run tests a couple of times and share the observation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've tried an additional test using timestamp and got the same result, but realized that Chrome is the cause. It seems that Chrome can issue requests to the different URLs at the same time but not for the same one. When I used Chrome and Firefox for each request, both ways to call result the same.